# Export Huge Volume of Data to flat files from tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I am using Oracle 11g. My requirement is to compare the data of two different db's.  There are around 350 tables in each db and out of these 350 tables, approx 40 tables have more than 1 million records. For data comparison, I wrote one perl script to compare using hash and tested with few files. Also, tried with unix awk command to check the performance and asked this forum on unix solution and got excellent help.

Now my problem is to find out the best way to extract data from Tables to files.
Both db's have same number of tables and each table will have same number of columns in both db i.e. the layout in both the db's is exactly the same.
options which i think and searched are
1) using sqlloader - I think performance will be bad in this case
2) using data pump - Not sure if i can extract few set of columns via sql by using data pump and load into text file
3) using bulk collect -- same as above. Is it possible to extract each table and from each table set of columns. if yes, how can it be done. Also what would be the performance.
4) sqlplus or anything else. I cannot download any software for this on my machine.

Basic sql for selecting set of columns from each table for both the db's can be done easily. I am looking at the best approach to export data into flat files.
Please suggest

Comment: Is the data in two different Oracle databases?  If so, why bother generating and comparing files?  Why not compare the data within Oracle directly?

Comment: This approach was considered earlier, However to compare column by column of a row of table which has millions of rows and that too a list of 350 tables from each db i.e total of 700 tables. Suppose A record contains 50 attributes and compare each attribute row by row and then generating the output in text file will be an expensive affair. Example of output of report (which perl is generating) is TableName, RowNumber, ColumnName, ColumnValueDB1, ColumnValueDB2 so thought of script as file processing is faster. Also, on database this operation will take a lot of time and expensive too.

Comment: I think generating files then comparing is much more difficult then using Toad or SQL Developer compare tools.

Comment: Have you thought about just doing transportable tablespaces or an  rman duplicate instead of all of this processing?  That is the only way that I would believe 100% that the two databases were exact at a moment in time.  I have used transport tablespaces for this task many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the database using DBMS_COMPARISON.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_comparison.htm#CHDHEFFJ

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental approach that is the least expensive (to the developer for sure) is to compare sets of things rather than string evaluations of files. Nothing can compare sets of things faster (and in less code) than the database itself. The use of database links and a wise use of the MINUS and INTERSECT operators is very powerful means towards this end.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below SQL this should be the fastest approach as you will be working inside the database. Access the table over the DB link in other database.

select *
from 
(
( select * from Table_In_Schema1
  minus 
  select * from Table_In_Schema2)
union all
( select * from Table_In_Schema2
  minus
  select * from Table_In_Schema1)
)